# Macbook System Profiler formatted

Tags: text-processing, osx, table

I want to format the output generated from macbook terminal command `system_profiler` and transpose the row values to columns under the same Application.

Here's a snippet of the file:

Firefox:

```
  Version: 32.0.3
  Obtained from: Identified Developer
  Last Modified: 28/09/2014 18:23
  Kind: Intel
  64-Bit (Intel): Yes
  Signed by: Developer ID Application: Mozilla Corporation, Developer ID Certification
  Location: /Applications/Firefox.app
  Get Info String: Firefox 32.0.3

Calendar:

  Version: 7.0
  Obtained from: Apple
  Last Modified: 18/03/2014 06:58
  Kind: Intel
  64-Bit (Intel): Yes
  Location: /Applications/Calendar.app
```

...and want the output to be like this image:

[image: 1]

Notes:

1. Not all columns will be filled per application
2. There's a maximum of 8 of this type of information (see the complete set under the Firefox application)
3. The leading padded spaces and line breaks between groups of information per Application

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F: ' # set fields separator to :
$1!="" && $2==""{i++;NAME[i]=$1} # if 1st field without second it is app.name
$2!=""{HEAD[$1]=1;DATA[NAME[i],$1]=$2 $3} # put variables name into array
#+ put variables into 2-dimention array app.name,var.name  
END{
printf("%s:","Application"); # first column in header
for (n in HEAD) printf("%s:",n); # print all var.name as header separated by :
print ""; # finish line by newline
for(i in NAME){ # for each app.name
  printf("%s:",NAME[i]); # print app.name
  for (n in HEAD) printf("%s:", DATA[NAME[i],n]); # print each variables corresponding to app.name
  print ""; # finish line by newline
  }
}' data.file | sed -E 's/:\s*/:/g' | column -s: -tn
```

`sed`    strips all spaces after `:`

`column` formats colums of text

Comment: thanks costas...most appreciated but when executing as a command line i have to feed the filename before performing the sed operation. How do i execute as a script against the file pls

Comment: @Jags If you have file with data just put its name after awk-script like `... }' data.file | sed ...` If you want to format the some command output let pipe it like `system_profiler | awk -F: ...`

Comment: Thanks, I did that but only works without then piping to sed otherwise it keeps prompting me to complete the command line. Also do you mind terribly explaining how this works, desperately trying to learn some awk. Many thanks Costas

Comment: @Jags What the error message `sed` produce?

Comment: When I include the filename before piping to sed command, it simply waits and is expecting another command

Comment: just realised you'd changed your command. It works and can direct to an output.file. Do you mind explaining how this works. Brilliant stuff. Many thanks.

Comment: @Jags Have put some comments in programm text

Comment: @Costas.....thank you once again. Awk is so powerful.